# Invite guardians from the same domain to Google Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

I'm trying to invite a guardian to a Classroom course using Api Explorer. The student and the guardian's emails are in the same domain (as in the case that a school teacher has a son attending his school). The requests returns OK, but the invitation email never comes. I've tried with the same student with emails from other domains and everything runs fine. I've found nothing in documentation about this, neither in Classroom nor Admin Console.

Comment: Can you please provide code which shows what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, Rafa, the problem doesn't seem to be about code, I've tried thru https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles.guardianInvitations/create and it doesn't work either. You can invite someuser@gmail.com to be a guardian to a_student@somedomain.com, where somedomain.com is a G Suite customer, but you can't invite some_parent@somedomain.com to be an a_student guardian, the invite never arrives and the pending invitation doesn't show up in a_student courses.

Comment: I'm unable to fully test this as I do not have a parent/guardian-child account access, though if you're following the steps on the Classroom API page and believe this could be a bug in the API, I suggest you file a report on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).